# Debian: `Suspend` does `Logout` instead of `Suspend`

Tags: suspend, logout, debian-buster

Today sudenly when i tried to `Suspend` it logged out instead of suspend. I've tried many different things but, couldn't get suspend to work again; viz.

1. `sudo mask suspend.target` > restart > `sudo mask suspend.target`
2. `sudo pm-suspend` works, but doesn't lock the screen. So, suspend operation works but, the default `suspend` command does `logout` now.

- OS: Debian 10.7
- Kernel: Linux 4.19.0-11-amd64 x86_64

Recent changes:

1. Added `deb unstable` to sources list and try to install latest firefox. It didn't because unmet dependency. Reverted changes. Still doesn't work
2. edited `fstab` to add ssd optimizations: `ssd,noatime,space_cache,commit=120,compress=astd`. This was the last know system change when first instance of this issue was experienced. On restart found out this is not correct for `ext4` so, corrected using Debian NetInst live USB. Current mount options: `noatime,errors=remount-ro`. After this it still doesn't work.

I would have to reinstall the system if i can't suspend.

EDIT: I even tried deleting `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` (which didn't have any uncommented line) to no avail.

Suspend is set on closing lid. Instead of suspend, it goes to `tty1` shell and asks me for a password. Then loads the Login screen when i login again to a new session not my old session. On manual suspend, the `tty1` shell blinks briefly and system goes to Login screen.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. To be able to suspend, linux needs both `suspend.target` & `sleep.target`.

To resolve the situation, do:

`sudo systemctl unmask suspend.target sleep.target`

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: this just worked for me after upgrading to 23.10, thanks!